# React-virtualized - scrollToIndex doesn't work with WindowScroller

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm working with `react-virtualized`, and trying to use the `scrollToIndex` feature, but I get an empty list when using it. (If I scroll, then my list show again).

Here is my code:

```
        <WindowScroller>
        {({ height, isScrolling, scrollTop }) => (
            <AutoSizer disableHeight>
                {({ width }) => (
                    <List
                        autoHeight
                        height={height}
                        rowCount={lines.length}
                        rowRenderer={({ index, key, style }) => rowRenderer({ index, isScrolling, key, style, lines, onDelete, toggle })}
                        rowHeight={145}
                        scrollTop={scrollTop}
                        scrollToIndex={100}
                        width={width}
                    />
                    )}
            </AutoSizer>
            )}
    </WindowScroller>
```

If I remove                         `scrollToIndex={100}`, everything works fine.

Does `scrollToIndex` works with `WindowScroller`? because I only found example of it with `List`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does scrollToIndex works with WindowScroller? because I only found example of it with List

Unfortunately this feature does not currently work when WindowScroller is being used because WS controls the scroll position (not the List itself). Using scrollToIndex while also using WindowScroller gives the List conflicting information and things break.

This is a question that has come up once or twice before so maybe it's something I will try to support eventually though.

**EDIT**

Since version **9.8.0**, WindowScroller supports scrollToIndex prop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really need this feature, I've been using `window.scrollTo(0, index * rowHeight);` as a workaround but it's not very accurate since the List doesn't always start at the top of the page. any better workaround? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not presently. Sorry!

Comment: @Anas any idea how I would work around a List with variable height? I need to scroll to an element down the List. the `window.scrollTo` solution wouldn't work for me I guess :)

Comment: Well, you have access to your own `rowHeight` getter function- so you could still compute the offset, but it wouldn't be the most efficient. If you're willing to pin to a specific release of react-virtualized, you could use the internal `_rowSizeAndPositionManager` property on `Grid` to ask it for the cached position (eg `gridRef._rowSizeAndPositionManager.getSizeAndPositionOfCell(rowNumber). offset`)

Comment: @brianvaughn Hi Brian, any chance to support this option in a future release?

Comment: It's supported in the current release candidate. Give it a spin: `npm i react-virtualized@next`

Comment: @brianvaughn Thank you very much, edited the answer.

Comment: Ah! Cheers for doing that.